# Android Studio Error When Importing Packages

Tags: android, android-studio, import, package

I am currently learning to use Android Studio and have been faced with the following errors when running the app:

```
Error:(19, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable Log
Error:(11, 21) error: package android.until does not exist
```

At the top of my project I have imported:

```
import android.until.log;
import android.view.View;
```

What is the reason for this error? Also, the import statements are greyed out at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a typo.  Should be android.util.log you have android.until.log.

Here is an example of using android.util.log:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {

    public void clickFunction(View view) {
        Log.i("Info", "Button Tapped!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks I did not notice that. Now it shows: Error:(11, 20) error: cannot find symbol class log
Error:(19, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable Log

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Comment: @ JJF Do you know what is causing my current error?

Comment: public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 
    public void clickFunction(View view) {
     
        Log.i("Info", "Button Tapped!");

    }